# OpenShift Pro - How To Increase Storage For Application

Tags: openshift

I have a **Tomcat 8** web app running on **OpenShift Pro**, it has **2Gb** storage allocated to it.

I want to **increase** the amount of storage to **4Gb**.

In the **Web Console**, when I look at the **Persistent Storage Claim** the only **Action** available is **Delete**. I am reluctant to do this for obvious reasons...

**What is the correct way to increase the storage available to an application?**

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there is no way to modify storage for an application.  You will need to create a new one of the required size. You can then start a pod which mounts both volumes and copy contents from one to the other. When you have cut over to new volume and happy release claim on the original.

<strike>1) I think you should be able to edit the size of a persistent volume using the CLI interface. If you execute:</strike>

```
oc edit pvc <name of volume>
```

You should get an editor with a YAML representation of the persistent volume, where you can edit the size of the claim.

2) This is really a feature which Red Hat should support.  I would open a ticket on [the support page](https://access.redhat.com/support/cases/#/case/new) so that this gets added in the future.

Comment: A normal user can't edit a ``pv``. A normal user can only edit a ``pvc``. Even so that will not work as that only comes into play when the initial volume claim is made. I don't believe that can be changed after the fact to increase the size of an existing volume.

Comment: There is a discussion on volume resizing, including volumes on AWS as used by OpenShift Online at https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/35941 Again, that requires  admin level access.

Comment: This is bad news. Computer systems tend to use more resources over time, data get bigger. There has to be a properly documented way of adding more file space when it is required. This will happen to LIVE systems that cannot afford to be down or crash...

Comment: @Lyndon Openshift is designed to run containerized applications, which should ideally be stateless (ie no data is stored on the container), and instead stored on a database or DFS.

Comment: Derek, are you saying that ALL filesystem data should be stored on S3 or something similar?

Comment: Essentially, yes.  This way, Openshift can scale and reschedule your container without having to worry about stateful data.

Comment: Openshift has some built in Cartridges for common databases.  Depending on your use case something like MongoDB might be a fit.  https://www.openshift.com/features/containers.html